# Is it acceptable in C++ to have a non incremented variable in a For Loop?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, coding-style

So I'm trying to learn C++ and I have this loop:

```
if (userNumber >= 0) 
{
     for(double i = userNumber; i < userNumber + 10; i)
     {
         cout << ++i << endl;
     }
}
```

This has the same output as:

```
if (userNumber >= 0) 
{
     for(double i = userNumber; i < userNumber + 10; i++)
     {
         cout << i + 1 << endl;
     }
}
```

Is the first form acceptable, or is it bad style?

Comment: `for(double i = ...` While the question itself has been answered, I'll just note that having a `double` as the control variable of a `for` loop is ill advised (except in very special cases, which shouldn't be a concern when you start learning C++). Due to the limited floating point precision, neither loop is guaranteed to always run exactly 10 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bad style of first snippet is to have unused statement `i`.
Prefer in this case:

```
for(int i = userNumber; i < userNumber + 10; /*empty*/)
{
    cout << ++i << endl;
}
```

For trivial case, the second snippet is better as clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Both are valid, the second one is more explicit and readable. Since `i` is not modified in the `for` loop block, one could instantly say how many times the loop will iterate.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` statement defined in the C++ standard as:

```
for ( for-init-statement; optional condition; optional expression) statement
```

and is equivalent to

```
{
    for-init-statement
    while ( condition ) {
        statement
        expression ;
    }
}
```

> except that names declared in the for-init-statement are in the same declarative-region as those declared in the condition, and except that a `continue` in statement (not enclosed in another iteration statement) will
>   execute expression before re-evaluating condition.

So both are valid.  But the second has more of a C++ style since the *expression* part is supposed to give you an idea of how the loop is controlled.